# Added JSfiddle link to original question, but edit rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106849/getcurrentposition-and-watchposition-are-deprecated-on-insecure-origins/37161798#37161798)

I added a JSFiddle link to the answer that was already present as a comment, so that users could find it easily. Why would such an edit be rejected?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12504816

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment was "Added JSfiddle link" but it seems that the jsfiddle was one provided by the answerer in a comment.

You didn't make that clear, had you done so it's more likely your change would have been approved.